# Implementing a Magic Wand for HTML5 <canvas>?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

Can anyone provide guidance on how to implement a magic wand tool for cropping images(w/tolerance) using the  element?

The idea is to give the user the power to crop out a background of an image based on the color values provided with a certain threshhold.

Comment: Question has been reworded to ask for help on implementation rather than external libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be very similar to [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill). If you choose to implement one of the algorithms linked, you should use a non-recursive queue based for JavaScript, since it's not very good for recursive calls. I have not implemented Flood fill my self, but it sounds very similar to Magic Wand.